# switch ($_GET['fav']) - Print Error

Tags: php

```
        161 <?php
        162 switch ($_GET['fav']) {
        163 case 0:
        165 echo "";
        166 break;
        167 case 1:
        168 echo "File Added.";
        169 break;
        170 } ?>
```

Print Error:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: fav in /***/theme/v7/Downloads-Item.php on line 162
```

The principle of operation:

```
http://www.example.com/websitepage        => error warning appears

http://www.example.com/websitepage?fav=1  => code work..
```

What's wrong? What is the reason for this error?

Comment: it's not an error, but a notice.

Comment: The error is occur when there is not variable defined. $_GET['fav'] is not defined, so it throws an error. You must check is variable set or not by `isset( $_GET['fav'] )` or change code as `switch( intval( $_GET['fav']))`

Comment: Thank you @TamilSelvan but white page and only error text.. -> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in ..... in line 162

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) and about a billion others.

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is no **`fav`** parameter in the URL

The second URL contains **`fav`** parameter , whereas the first one does not and thus you get an undefined index notice.